# javascript: namespace pollution

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, global-variables

I am trying to submit my addon to the mozilla site but I am getting this damn warning:

[image]

The code (in mf_options.js) is pretty simple (and i think the problem is only between the "start storage" and "end storage":

```
// start Storage
var url = "http://mafiaafire.com";
var ios = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
          .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
var ssm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/scriptsecuritymanager;1"]
          .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptSecurityManager);
var dsm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/dom/storagemanager;1"]
          .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMStorageManager);
var uri = ios.newURI(url, "", null);
var principal = ssm.getCodebasePrincipal(uri);
var storage = dsm.getLocalStorageForPrincipal(principal, "");
// end Storage



function display_blocked_list1() {

  var list = storage.getItem('domain_list_original');
  if (list !== undefined) {

    var strSingleLineText = list.replace(new RegExp( " ", "g" ),    "<br>"  );

    var status = document.getElementById("div1");
 status.innerHTML = strSingleLineText;
   }

  var list2 = storage.getItem('domain_list_redirect');
  if (list2 !== undefined) {

    // Strip out all line breaks.
    var strSingleLineText2 = list2.replace(new RegExp( " ", "g" ),  "<br>"  );

    var status2 = document.getElementById("div2");
 status2.innerHTML = strSingleLineText2;
   }


  var list3 = storage.getItem('list_expiry_date');

  if (list3 !== undefined) {



var dateArray = list3.split(",");
var future_date = new Date(dateArray[0],dateArray[1],dateArray[2]);
future_date.setDate(future_date.getDate()+2);

    var status2 = document.getElementById("div3");
 status2.innerHTML = future_date;

  }
// ##################################################

}
```

Comment: Might be a stupid suggestion, but did you go to that link?

Comment: I did, but it's a little too much "higher javascript" for me :( I am used to the old easier way and am learning the newer stuff.

Comment: Just wrap your code in a `(function() { /* code here */ })();`

Comment: Ok, did that, but when I try to call it like this `<body onLoad="display_blocked_list1()">` I am getting an error

Comment: Note that this warning is safe to ignore for scripts that load into your own windows. However, when your scripts load into the browser window or other common windows like Preferences (typically via an overlay) then any of your global variables should have unique names - because otherwise other extensions could choose to use the same names for their variables and there would be a huge mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code in a function envelope so your `var`s are local to that function body, and explicitly attach anything you want global to the global object.

```
(function (global) {

  // your code here

  global.myGlobalVar = myVar

}(this));
```

Comment: I am getting the above error for 8 different files, can you make the changes in the above file and I'll do the other files based on what you did please?

Comment: @Ryan, No.  I don't have access to your source code, nor should I.  If you have multiple source files then you should look into using a compressor to combine them into one.  Closure compiler has the output wrapper option which you can use to add the envelope around the compiled output.

Comment: @Mike, no, I meant can you do what you wrote to the above code please? or wait a min and will do it and you can tell me if its right.

Comment: @Ryan, Did you mean to put an absolute URL there?

Comment: yep, its www.ezee.se/tests/testing.js

Comment: I tried what you wrote, but how do I call it in the html page where I am presently doing this: <body onLoad="display_blocked_list1()">

Comment: @Ryan, you need to export `display_blocked_list1` as a global by doing something like `global.display_blocked_list1 = display_blocked_list1;` as shown above.

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely have a look at the link. However I also got this message and I'm fairly sure my code does not contain any (polluting) global variables.

But if this is exactly the code you use, then any function and variable you declare will be global. In its simplest case, wrap the code in an anonymous function call:

```
(function() {
    // your code here
}());
```

If you need a global variable, because you have to call function from XUL elements,  make sure you only have **one**. Create it inside the function call above with

```
window.YourPluginNamespace = {
    // all functions or "subspaces" here
};
```

Comment: But this is not from my main JS file... this is from a secondary JS file that just has some helper functions not really related to the main js file that is the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using too many global variables, those defined outside of a function.

Imagine this scenario: my addon, **Foo**, uses a variable called `sheep`.

```
var sheep = 10;
```

Your addon, **Bar**, uses a variable also called `sheep`:

```
var sheep = 20;
```

When I go to access `sheep`, how can I be assured your addon hasn't modified it? This is the same reason addons use anonymous functions `foo = function() {`, because they are local.

To make you global variables more local, wrap your *whole* script in an anonymous function:

```
(function() {
  var sheep = 10;
}());
```

Now, you can do whatever you wish with `sheep` and it will be local. Keep in mind, though, that you'd need some better scaffolding if you plan on making your application more complex. This method isn't completely bulletproof or scalable...

Comment: If this isnt bulletproof or scalable, why use it?

Comment: It isn't *completely* bulletproof, but it's a little bit bulletproof as long as the bullets aren't too high-spec. That is, good enough for most purposes. Note Felix King's answer for how to make functionality inside your anonymous function available elsewhere on the page (e.g., from your onload).